# How to port this assembly maximum number of a list program from 32-bit to x86-64?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, 32bit-64bit, ld

This is a program given in the book '[Programming from the ground up](https://download-mirror.savannah.gnu.org/releases/pgubook/ProgrammingGroundUp-1-0-booksize.pdf)' by Jonathan Bartlett to find the maximum number in a list:

```
#PURPOSE: This program finds the maximum number of a
# set of data items.
#
#VARIABLES: The registers have the following uses:
#
# %edi - Holds the index of the data item being examined
# %ebx - Largest data item found
# %eax - Current data item
#
# The following memory locations are used:
#
# data_items - contains the item data. A 0 is used
# to terminate the data
#
.section .data
data_items:                    #These are the data items
.long 3,67,34,222,45,75,54,34,44,33,22,11,66,0
.section .text
.globl _start
_start:
movl $0, %edi                  # move 0 into the index register
movl data_items(,%edi,4), %eax # load the first byte of data
movl %eax, %ebx                # since this is the first item, %eax is
                               # the biggest
start_loop:                    # start loop
cmpl $0, %eax                  # check to see if we’ve hit the end
je loop_exit
incl %edi                      # load next value
movl data_items(,%edi,4), %eax
cmpl %ebx, %eax                # compare values
jle start_loop                 # jump to loop beginning if the new
# one isn’t bigger
movl %eax, %ebx                # move the value as the largest
```

unfortunately the assembly programs given in the book are for 32 bit processors FWIU. So I'm translating the programs for 64 bit with some help from [https://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/gasexamples/](https://cs.lmu.edu/%7Eray/notes/gasexamples/). Here is my code(which is not working) for 64 bit systems:

```
#variables: the registers have the following uses:
# %rdx - holds the index of the data item being examined
# %rbx - largest data item found
# %rcx - current data item
# the following memory locations are used:
# data_items - contains the item data. 0 is used to terminate the data.
data_items:
        .long 8,9,3,4,15,8,0

.global _start
.text

_start:
        mov $0, %rdx                            # move 0 into the index register
        mov data_items(,%rdx,4), %rcx           # load the first byte of data
        mov %rcx, %rbx                          # since this is the first item, %rcx is the biggest

start_loop:
        cmp $0, %rcx                            # check to see if we've hit the end
        je loop_exit
        inc %rdx                                # load next value
        mov data_items(,%rdx,4), %rcx
        cmp %rbx, %rcx
        jle start_loop
        mov %rcx, %rbx                          # move the value as the largest
        jmp start_loop

loop_exit:
        #%rdi is the status code for the exit system call
        mov $60, %rax
        mov %rbx, %rdi                          # moving the final value in %rbx to %rdi to return
        syscall
```

What is wrong in my code?

I suspect that `.long` doesn't work the same way in 64 bit assembly code.

I tried to debug the code in gdb here is the output:

```
Reading symbols from ./a.out...

(gdb) break 1
Breakpoint 1 at 0x401000: file max.s, line 11.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/hackasaur/Desktop/assembly/a.out

Breakpoint 1, _start () at max.s:11
11              mov $0, %rdx                                                                            # move 0 into the index register
(gdb)stepi
 12              mov data_items(,%rdx,4), %rcx           # load the first byte of data
(gdb) info registers
rax            0x0                 0
rbx            0x0                 0
rcx            0x0                 0
rdx            0x0                 0
rsi            0x0                 0
rdi            0x0                 0
rbp            0x0                 0x0
rsp            0x7ffffffee160      0x7ffffffee160
r8             0x0                 0
r9             0x0                 0
r10            0x0                 0
r11            0x0                 0
r12            0x0                 0
r13            0x0                 0
r14            0x0                 0
r15            0x0                 0
rip            0x401007            0x401007 <_start+7>
eflags         0x202               [ IF ]
cs             0x33                51
ss             0x2b                43
ds             0x0                 0
es             0x0                 0
fs             0x0                 0
gs             0x0                 0
(gdb) stepi
13              mov %rcx, %rbx                                                                  # since this is the first item, %rcx is the biggest
(gdb) info registers
rax            0x0                 0
rbx            0x0                 0
rcx            0x900000008         38654705672
rdx            0x0                 0
rsi            0x0                 0
rdi            0x0                 0
rbp            0x0                 0x0
rsp            0x7ffffffee160      0x7ffffffee160
r8             0x0                 0
r9             0x0                 0
r10            0x0                 0
r11            0x0                 0
r12            0x0                 0
r13            0x0                 0
r14            0x0                 0
r15            0x0                 0
rip            0x40100f            0x40100f <_start+15>
eflags         0x202               [ IF ]
cs             0x33                51
ss             0x2b                43
ds             0x0                 0
es             0x0                 0
fs             0x0                 0
gs             0x0                 0
```

I found that there is this gibberish value `38654705672` getting loaded in rcx register in the line 12 `mov data_items(,%rdx,4), %rcx` instead of 8. Every time something is loaded using `mov data_items(,%rdx,4), %rcx` some big gibberish value is loaded.

I am using this command to assemble and link:
`as max.s -o max.o && ld max.o && ./a.out`
and I'm getting an exit code of 4 for the above list of numbers using `echo $?` which should be 15 in this case if it worked correctly.

Comment: The array elements are still 32-bit so you should be doing 32-bit loads and compares on the data with 32-bit registers, only using 64-bit operand-size (and versions of register names) for the pointer math.  `mov data_items(,%rdx,4), %rcx` loads 2 adjacent elements.  Look at compiler output for an example if you write this in C for an `int[]` array: https://godbolt.org/

Comment: "I suspect that .long doesn't work the same way in 64 bit assembly code."  Au contraire, it works exactly the same - it assembles a 32-bit value, yet as Peter says your code treats them as 64-bit.  Yes, this means that it doesn't necessarily match the size of C's `long` type.

Comment: Look at the hex value, not decimal.  It makes sense there: `0x900000008` makes it clear you're just loading two 32-bit elements into 1 register, resulting in  `9<<32 | 8`.  Yes the decimal value is gibberish because 10 isn't a power of 2.

Comment: Related: [In this x86-64 instruction encoding documentation, what's the use of having 8, 16, 32, 64 bit GPRs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64482535) and [64 bit assembly, when to use smaller size registers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6577458)

Comment: And found a nearly exact duplicate: [Assembly code to return smallest integer in array instead randomly returns either last or second to last number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60358473) is min instead of max and NASM syntax, but exactly the same problem: doing 64-bit qword loads from 32-bit dword data (aka `.long` aka C `int[]`).